# Oracle PL/SQL: How to detect if a procedure is ALREADY running?

Tags: oracle, procedure

Please suppose that we have a procedure inside a package:

```
MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROCEDURE
```

This procedure could be launched from many users.

How can I modify the procedure in order to detect if the procedure is ***at present running*** since launched from another user?

What is the safest way to detect it?

Thank you for considering my request.

EDIT 01: "It'll depend on why you need to know if a proc is already running or not" **==> If the procedure is at present running, it WON'T be launched again.**

Comment: I'd probably just create a table which stores at least the username, package, procedure and start time, and then change the procedure to insert a row into the table when it was being called and then delete it afterwards. I'm looking forward to seeing other people's suggestions though! Hmm, alternatively, you could use dbms_application_info calls to set the module and action, and then it's visible what each session is up to in v$session. It'll depend on why you need to know if a proc is already running or not.

Comment: @Boneist: I think you'd still have a race condition. I'm not aware of any synchronization primitives which are accessible in PL/SQL but my knowledge is far from exhaustive. Is there anything like a mutex available in the Oracle PL/SQL API's anywhere?

Comment: I can remember that there was a guy in my previous job that told me they used Oracle context functionality for something like that. Have a look on this article:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5002.htm
It must have been the 'accessed globally' context where you can simply put name-value couples for all the parameters you want. I can't try it now unfortunately but this looks promising.
On the other hand, using as simple solution as using the status table and writing to it with autonomous transaction makes even more sense :)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis: there's a mutex functionality with dbms_lock.request functionality but not sure what the OP is trying to achieve: wait until the other one finishes or do something else in that time with the same procedure. If this is for wait purposes, using mutex could be the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_appinf.htm#CHECEIEB) package for such information.

```
PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(..) IS
BEGIN
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO('MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROCEDURE running');

   ... All your stuff

DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(NULL);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_CLIENT_INFO(NULL);
    RAISE;
END MY_PROCEDURE;
```

In order to check it, you can select V$SESSION View:

```
SELECT * 
FROM v$session 
WHERE client_info = 'MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROCEDURE running';
```

If you get any records then the procedure is running.

Comment: Thank you for you example code.  And what if I forget to set NULL in case of exception?  Is there any way to reset after having logged out from the Oracle session?

Comment: client_info is related to a session, so when the session is closed then of course the client_info also disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what others have mentioned and a quick perusal of the DBMS_LOCK package header it appears that you can use the various DBMS_LOCK routines to accomplish what you're trying to do. If I'm reading the header comments correctly you'd want to call `ALLOCATE_UNIQUE` to get a handle to a unique, named lock, then you'd call `REQUEST` with the locking mode set to 'x' (Exclusive) to try to grab the lock. If the `REQUEST` call returns 0 you can go ahead and run your routine. When done, call `RELEASE` to make the lock available to the next caller.

Best of luck.